# React Native Instagram style story videos with progress bars - progress bars not re-rendering

Tags: javascript, react-native, video

Having major troubles with getting a progress bar to follow a video duration in React Native. It doesn't appear that the progress bars want to re-render.

My code is rather long, so I've put it into a Gist: https://gist.github.com/Jamesking56/7775eb32eba14305d1c2c3cbdbf59333

Any ideas how I can get the progress bars to follow along with the videos?

Cheers.

Comment: Is there any change if you reduce this to just one fixed story instead of returning from `stories.map`?

Comment: @GenericUser I did try a fixed one and it also didn't re-render when the video is playing